# Append values in list nested in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to add stock prices to a dictionary and append the recent value at the end.
It should be running till cancelled. So a while True loop might be appropriate?
Furthermore I would like to have the amount of prices in the list restricted to the recent 3.
I use yfinance as a stock price library.

What I need is that it appends the price of stock#1 to the list within the dictionary. Then #2, then #3. Then starts over with #1 again but appends it to the same dictionary.
In my approach it iterates over stock#1 over and over again.

Result should be like:

```
{
    "AAPL": [137.13, 137.45, 138.02],
    "TESL": [696.69, 696.72, 670.1],
    "MSFT": [252.99, 253.01, 254.01],
}
```

What I tried so far, but didn't work is:

```
stocks = ['AAPL', 'TESL', 'MSFT']
dict_akt = {}

while True:
    list_temp = []
    for stock in stocks:
        sto = yf.Ticker(stock)
        cur_price = sto.info['currentPrice']
        list_temp.append(cur_price)

        dict_akt[stock] = list_temp
```

The bad output is:

```
{
    "AAPL": [137.13, 696.69, 252.99],
    "TSLA": [137.13, 696.69, 252.99],
    "MSFT": [137.13, 696.69, 252.99],
}
```

Comment: can you post the output you are getting

Comment: your code is not indented properly

Comment: @deadshot yes, you are right. but in the original version, it is

Comment: @deadshot {'AAPL': [137.13], 'TSLA': [696.69], 'MSFT': [252.99]}

Comment: you are initializing list inside for loop that's why you are getting single element

Comment: @deadshot I have updated my code and the bad output. It adds it to the wrong sub-list. Any idea?

Comment: The list for each ticker is the same object, thus all changes are reflected in all elements

Comment: you should use defaultdict, it's suits your usecase

Comment: You won't even get the bad output from that code because you have an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

you should just create lists in the `dict_akt` and manipulate those directly

```py
stocks = ['AAPL', 'TESL', 'MSFT']
dict_akt = {}

# init lists
for stock in stocks:
    dict_akt[stock] = []

while True:
    for stock in stocks:
        sto = yf.Ticker(stock)
        cur_price = sto.info['currentPrice']
        dict_akt[stock].append(cur_price)
        #check size and pop first element if desired size exceeded
        if len(dict_akt[stock]) > 3:
            dict_akt[stock].pop(0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. That's what I will use. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow break out of your loop in order to see any results so let's assume that you want to run for at least some period of time.

The public APIs that underpin yfinance are notoriously slow.

Note also that the *info* dictionary may not always contain keys that you might expect, so you should check.

This code manages the size of the lists (latest three entries) "manually". You could consider using a deque but that would depend on how you wanted to access the results.

```
import time
import yfinance
import requests_cache

results = dict()
tickers = 'AAPL', 'TESL', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'ORCL'
duration = 60 # seconds
session = requests_cache.CachedSession('yfinance.cache')
session.headers['User-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'

start = time.perf_counter()

while time.perf_counter() - start < duration:
    for ticker in tickers:
        stock = yfinance.Ticker(ticker, session=session)
        if (price := stock.info.get('currentPrice')):
            results.setdefault(ticker, []).append(price)
            if len(results[ticker]) > 3:
                results[ticker].pop(0)

print(results)
```

**Output:**

```
{'AAPL': [137.13, 137.13, 137.13], 'MSFT': [252.99, 252.99, 252.99], 'GOOG': [2228.55, 2228.55, 2228.55], 'ORCL': [67.14, 67.14, 67.14]}
```

**Notes:**

All the values are the same because this was run on a non-trading day (Saturday). The *currentPrice* key is missing for TESL.

Python 3.8+ required

You will need to *pip install requests_cache* if you don't already have it.

Use of a cached session can potentially improve performance

Comment: Thanks bud. Do you know any better library for live stock prices than yfinance?

Comment: @JonesL Google will lead you to numerous resources. Some free, some not